# Why does my xts object have an X in the index field?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

Say I have a basic `xts` object.

```
a <- xts(order.by = Sys.Date()-1:5,(6:10))
a
           [,1]
2019-04-10   10
2019-04-11    9
2019-04-12    8
2019-04-13    7
2019-04-14    6
```

However I sometimes get this:

```
       [,1]
X2019-04-10   10
X2019-04-11    9
X2019-04-12    8
X2019-04-13    7
X2019-04-14    6
```

It looks like the data has an "X" in front.

If I try to see the index I get:

```
index(a)[1]
"2019-04-10"
```

but if I have an "X "I get:

```
index(a)[1]
"2019-04-10 UTC"
```

I am using source R data created by someone else. As far as I can tell, it is always of the same format, but when I have the "X", the `xts` does not behave as expected especially with merge or rbind especially with normal data.

**Update:**

Here is the head of the `dput(Xdata)` as requested.

```
dput(head(temp))
structure(c(116.625, 116.34375, 116.460938, 116.296875, 116.265625, 
116.4375), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1511913600, 
1.512e+09, 1512086400, 1512345600, 1512432000, 1512518400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Close.Price"))
           Close.Price
2017-11-29     116.6250
2017-11-30     116.3438
2017-12-01     116.4609
2017-12-04     116.2969
2017-12-05     116.2656
2017-12-06     116.4375
```

The only thing that looks strange to me is that one of the index values is 1.512e+09 instead of the full integer. I have no idea how to fix that.

Update 2:
The X only shows up in Rstudio if using the View command.

```
X2018.02.22     114.2188
X2018.02.23     114.3828
X2018.02.26     114.4375
X2018.02.27     114.1484
X2018.02.27.1   114.1484
```

If I look at the index itself the only difference is that the X has UTC displayed in the index.

I think that the duplicate entry with 2018.02.27.1 is responsible for the X I would expect it to simply be a duplicated date. If I remove that second date with head() the X goes away. 
I am using R 3.5.3 and xts 0.11-2. I recently updated R and all packages.

**I think I finally got it.**
After using Cettt's code to clean the index, I used: `temp = temp[!duplicated(index(temp))]` to remove extra duplicates and finally the X is gone.
I think the original data has some corruption. And these steps clean it up.

**Update 4:**
I found a bigger issue with the X's. If I output the data frame with fwrite the index is printed with the X. This adversely affects output file readability and usability. Removing duplicates is not a good solution as sometimes duplicates are necessary. I do this regularly and never encountered these issues before.
My packages seem to match others without issue. I can only assume it is my Rstuio version 1.2.1335 that is the problem. Can anyone think of a solution?

**Update 5**
The issue also happens with Rgui 3.5.3 with View() (which I did not know it had) so the problem is not with Rstuio, but with R itself???

**Update 6**
I used a clean machine and tried different versions of R. R 3.4.4 with xts 0.11-2 and zoo 1.8-5 did not have the same issue. 3.4.4 did not have a native View() function so it required Rstudio. In R 3.5.x with the same package versions View() is available in the Rgui and they all display and print the X.

Comment: hi, can you post `head(dput(X_data))` of a timeseries which has the X infront?

Comment: hi, for me there is no "X" in the printed time series:
I am using R 3.5.2, xts_0.11-2 and  zoo_1.8-4

Comment: The X only shows up in Rstudio if I View() the time series the actual Index is either with or without the UTC.

Comment: for me there is also no "X" in the Rstudio in the View Pane (RStudio Version 1.1.463)

Comment: I am using Rstudio 1.2.1335. I have the X with basic duplicates: `a <- xts(order.by = Sys.Date()-1:5,(6:10))
b <- xts(order.by = Sys.Date()-5:10,(10:15))                                            View(rbind(a,b))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the "X" comes from (I cannot reproduce this behavior), but maybe you can get rid of it like this:

```
index(df) <- as.Date(format(index(df), tz = ""))
```

Comment: Thanks this fix did not remove the X in View, however, it fixed the Index the point that I can compare indexes and merge, rbind and such work normally.